# Matching two columns to get the desired value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
A               C           D
12:58:09        12:58:09    400.9
12:58:16        12:58:10    468.0
12:58:20        12:58:11    425.9
12:58:34        12:58:12    432.4
12:58:38        12:58:13    439.3
12:58:49        12:58:14    442.5
12:58:53        12:58:15    445.2
12:58:56        12:58:16    447.2
12:59:00        12:58:17    449.7
12:59:04        12:58:18    450.4
12:59:07        12:58:19    453.9
12:59:11        12:58:20    454.3
```

I have a data set like this. I want to make a new helper column `B` that matches column `A` and `C`  and gives the value `D`. So my `B`should look like 400.9, 447.2, 454.3, and so on. Can anyone suggest me what approach should I use for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) is intended to do.  Using your provided sample data, use this in cell B1 and copy down: `=VLOOKUP(A1,C:D,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in column B and drag it down:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,$C$1:$D$100,2,FALSE)`